# Правильно отдать логотип?

Tags: дизайн, веб-дизайн, photoshop

Клиент попросил сделать логотип, он будет использоваться на сайте, визитках, документах и тд.
Логотип простой, текстовый(цифры). Попросил еще в векторном формате прислать.
Вопрос:
1. Какие размеры логотипа отдавать клиенту?
2. В каком формате?
3. Если попросил в векторе, то нужно еще делать не только в PS, но и в AI?

Comment: 1. спросить. как минимум 100%. если вектор, то хватит одного файла - это же веткор, а вот в растре вроде PNG нужно знать какие надо и сделать несколько.

Comment: 3. вектор - это AI, а PS растровый,

Comment: 2. спросить 4 символа нужно4 символа нужно4 символа нужно4 символа нужно4 символа нужно

Comment: @Rou1997, PS (PostScript) — это не жестко детерминированный формат. Он может содержать и векторные, и растровые составляющие. Основное отличие от  EPS: PS содержит специфичную информацию о том устройстве (виртуальном принтере в частном случае),на котором он был создан. EPS такой информации не содержит.

Comment: @PavelDmitrenko Ошибка: думал, что под PS имеется в виду Photoshop (который на самом деле PSD) А может и не ошибка...

Comment: @Rou1997 С PSD ситуация ровно аналогичная: этот формат является контейнером, в который можно «положить» в т.ч. и векторные данные. Один из примеров этого - [SmartObjects](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/create-smart-objects.html)

Comment: @PavelDmitrenko но в фотошопе рисуют растр

Comment: @Rou1997 Это неверная предпосылка. [см пример](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/drawing-vector-vs-pixel-shapes-in-photoshop-cs6/) Просто PhotoShop не специализированный инструмент, поэтому функционал работы с вектором (с кривыми Безье) применяется нечасто.

Comment: @PavelDmitrenko Важно что применяется, а не как "по книжке". а то будете говорить в ТЗ дизайнеру "сделайте в psd с кривыми" - раз скажете, два скажете, три, пять, а на шестой забудете уточнение про кривые и получите растр. Эргономика-с

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61992/discussion-between-pavel-dmitrenko-and-rou1997).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Практика показывает, что клиент не всегда знает, что именно (с технической точки зрения!) ему требуется (если речь, конечно, не идет о рекламном агентстве или хорошо подготовленном клиенте).

Очень часто клиенту передается только одно растровое изображение, и клиент удовлетворяется этим.

Далее, при производстве какой-либо продукции с использованием результатов работы иллюстратора, у сотрудников производства возникает вопрос: где взять векторное изображение?

Часто бывает так, что связь с исполнителем уже потеряна, и в производство идет либо растровое превью (в результате получаем заведомо низкокачественный результат), либо клиент повторно тратит средства и время на отрисовку илююстрации (что тоже, прямо скажем, не служит улучшению качества изначальной работы).

## Итак, клиенту, если не указано иное, передают две составляющие *(это минимально возможный набор)*:

**1. Preview (файл предпросмотра) иллюстрации.** 
Фон — в общем случае — белый *(если иллюстрация сделана не вывороткой)*.
Формат — png или jpg.
Размер — для комфортного экранного просмотра:  по высоте около 800 пикселей. Размер не принципиален — главное, чтобы не слишком мелкий, и не огромный. 
Цветовая модель — RGB.

В названии файла желательно использовать префикс/суффикс «preview», дабы ни у кого не возникло желания использовать именно этот файл в производстве, и было понимание того, что, кроме этого «preview» существуют и файл для производства.

**2. Векторный файл в формате EPS.**
**Шрифты** в кривых *(«Type / Create outlines» в Adobe Illustrator)*.
В особых случаях *(оговаривается отдельно)* возможна передача работы со шрифтами не в кривых с обязательным приложением файлов шрифтов, используемых в иллюстрации *(но здесь требуется учесть, что шрифты являются предметом интеллектуальной собственности их разработчика)*

**Геометрический размер**:
Если работа не является законченным изделием с четко определенными размерами (буклет, листовка и тп) значения не имеет, главное придерживаться здравого смысла.
*Например, можно предположить, что заказчик захочет распечатать работу на стандартном листе А4, и сделать размеры ArtBoard'а и самой иллюстрации таким образом, чтобы иллюстрация органично выглядела на листе формата А4.*

**Цветовая модель**:
В зависимости от области применения.
Для офсетной/цифровой печати — CMYK, для Web — RGB.

**Формат файла:** 
Для максимальной совместимости с любым ПО предпочтительный формат — EPS, т.к. Encapsulated PostScript является, по сути, отраслевым стандартом.

Файл PS (PostScript) передавать не следует, это формат для CTP/CTF (устройств вывода на формы).

AI, CDR и прочие проприетарные форматы лучше не использовать из-за возможных проблем с совместимостью.

Comment: +1. Это все достаточно субъективно. Если клиент не знает как ему надо - отдавайте так. Если знает - пусть сам скажет.

Answer (score 0):

1. Если это векторная картинка то это не имеет значения
2. Если на сайте то <kbd>.svg</kbd> если визитки то скорее всего <kbd>.cdr</kbd>
3. Делать придется в AI но набросать можно и PS